# How do I create an array with infinite elements or something, in python?

Tags: python, arrays, string

I am trying to create a python array that can hold as many strings as the user enters. I am trying to implement it in a loop, like this :

```
(Loop:)

Enter the string: 

array[1] = (string entered by user)

Enter the next string:

array[2] = (second string entered by user)

....

Enter the nth string:

array[n] = (nth string entered by user)
```

How can I achieve this? I have heard of dynamic arrays and lists and stuff, but I can't figure them out.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why have I been down-arrowed? I am new here, please inform me of what I've done before ruining my reputation. I'm trying to get to 15.

Comment: Don't know why. The only thing I can think of is that they think you did not properly search first. Usually you only ask a question on SO if a reasonable attempt to find the solution failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default lists in Python are dynamic arrays. You can simply initialize it with:

```
data = []
```

and use:

```
data.append(item)
```

to add an element at the end.

For example:

```
data = []

while True:
    print('Enter the string:')
    data.append(input())
```

This will go on until all the memory of your machine is exhausted.

You can also for instance specify a way to *stop* asking the user for more data. For instance if the user enters `'-1'`, you can say the loop should stop:

```
data = []
while True:
    print('Enter the string:')
    the_input = input()
    if the_input == '-1':
        break
    data.append(the_input)
#do something with the collected data
```

Now if you for instance run this code: the code will query for input until you enter `-1` (I think it is rather obvious how you can change the stopword). Then `data` contains all data entered before and you can process it somehow.

Comment: Surely the OP wants to `break` eventually (based on some keyword)

Comment: @Chris_Rands: yeah, I was getting to that point ;). Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is truly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
all_the_things = list()
for x in items:
    all_the_things.append(x)
```

For more reading: [Python Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add to a list, use append

```
data = []
data.append('whatever')
```

You haven't asked about how to get the input, so I assume you can do that.
Do bear in mind your computer will not have infinite storage - at some point you will run out of memory if you do this in a loop for ever.